# How can two AppEngine applications inter-communicate?

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to build an application in Google App Engine, but i have some question and don't know how to solve it.

I try to build two application, one is get a String from user, and other is process the String like divide or encrypt.

My question is how to transmit the String between two application in Google App Engine? And can I build an application just process the String, don't present the WEB page.

Any one can give me some tips? thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you want to split a simple function into two separate applications? It sounds to me as though the problem that you are trying to solve is nothing more than a simple request/response that AppEngine does very easily and naturally. I strongly suggest that you go through the examples in the Getting Started Guide:; https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/

Comment: @user1353777:Why you want two separate applications?

Comment: I want to simulate two different service provider, one can get String from user, and other is process the string. User just have to know the first service provider.

Answer (score 4):

The only way for two AppEngine applications to communicate with one another is through the normal HTTP request/response model. For your case, we'll have App A, which answers requests from a User, who provides a string to be processed. App B will receive requests from App A, which passes along the string to be processed.

1. *App A* handles the URL `/providestring?string=...` where `...` is some arbitrary value
2. *App B* handles the URL `/processstring?string=...` where `...` is some arbitrary value
3. *User* uses a browse or writes an application that makes a call to `/providestring`
4. *App A's* URL-handling code runs and extracts the value of the `string` parameter
5. *App A* uses [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) to call *App B's* `/processstring`
6. *App B's* URL-handling code runs and extracts the value of the `string` parameter and does whatever kind of processing it does and
   sends some sort of response to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have a shared database.  App A would intake user data and save it to the database.  App B would pull the user data and process it.

An Accepted feature request is for multiple App Engine applications to share datastore access [1].

Multiple App Engine applications can share access to Google Cloud SQL instances [2].

```
To grant access to your App Engine application:

From the Google Cloud SQL pane of the APIs Console, find the instance that you 
want to grant access to and click the on the name of your instance.
Click on the Instance settings button on the instance's dashboard.
On the Instance settings window that appears, enter your Google App Engine
application ID under the Authorized applications section. You can grant access to
multiple applications, by entering them one at a time.
```

Note: you can achieve this with one app using the datastore. Here are a couple of accepted patterns:

1. A RequestHandler takes in user data, queues a task to process the data and save it.
2. A RequestHandler takes in user data & saves it.  A cron job pulls all recent models of that type, processes them, and saves the processed data.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300

[2] https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/before_you_begin#configure_access_control

Comment: Both of which are nice, but neither of which really help the user with their question.

Comment: I suppose I left out the bit "if you wanted to use a shared database where one intakes from the user & writes to db, and the other reads from the db & processes the data, this is how you could do it"